# Creating a Slideshow for Quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am currently building a photo album, and I am using AngularJS and CSS, and the pictures I am using are showing up way too big.  No matter what I do, I can not get the pictures to resize and would like some insight as to whether someone can see what I am doing wrong.  I know I can resize in Photoshop, but when I do this, they won't show up correctly in the preview.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. My code is as follows for the JS....

```
'use strict';

angular.module('example366', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

// Set of Photos
$scope.photos = [
    {src: 'Images/KyahMaxCabin.jpg', desc: 'Kids Cabin', height: "250px", width: "300px"},
    {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8449/7918424278_4835c85e7a_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 02'},
    {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8457/7918424412_bb641455c7_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 03'},
    {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8179/7918424842_c79f7e345c_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 04'},
    {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8315/7918425138_b739f0df53_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 05'},
    {src: 'http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8461/7918425364_fe6753aa75_b.jpg', desc: 'Image 06'}
];

// initial image index
$scope._Index = 0;

// if a current image is the same as requested image
$scope.isActive = function (index) {
    return $scope._Index === index;
};

// show prev image
$scope.showPrev = function () {
    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index > 0) ? --$scope._Index : $scope.photos.length - 1;
};

// show next image
$scope.showNext = function () {
    $scope._Index = ($scope._Index < $scope.photos.length - 1) ? ++$scope._Index : 0;
};

// show a certain image
$scope.showPhoto = function (index) {
    $scope._Index = index;
};
});
```

I downloaded the code from a tutorial website, and the first picture is the only one of mine so far.  I wanted to play around with it and see what would happen before I added a lot of pictures.  So the code for the first photo is mine, and would just like to get some feedback on how to change the size.  I am just starting in JavaScript and so this is all kind of new to me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should also show us the html lines where you're placing this slider, and the relevant css which is styling the image. Hard to answer otherwise. 
You probably don't need to write extra js, you can probably fix your resizing problem with simple css styling of the img elements in the slider. It could be as simple as this:

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Of course, I'm not sure how your javascript sets this slider up in the document, so I don't know the specific CSS selector you need to use to target your img elements inside of the slider. Almost certainly your problem can be fixed by targeting your img elements with css and adjusting one or a few properties.

Comment: note: doing width: 100%; will make your images fit to the width of whatever container they are in